# Why Swift protocol conforming values are treated as Value types by default?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have a protocol, which only describes an interface.

```
protocol SampleProtocol {
var message: String? { get set }}
```

Why does the compiler treat the conforming value/object always as a Value type?

Sample Example,

```
 // Protocol value usage
import Foundation


protocol SampleProtocol {
    var message: String? { get set }
}

final class SampleObject: SampleProtocol {
    var message: String?
}


final class Controller {

    var sampleValue: SampleProtocol! {
        didSet {
            print("New value has been set")
        }
    }
}


let controller = Controller()
controller.sampleValue = AlphaObject() // Correctly prints "New value has been set"
controller.sampleValue.message = "New message" // Prints again "New value has been set", like for value types
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your protocol `SampleProtocol` could be adopted by a `class` or a `struct`.  Swift is using the behavior of the value type which is the more restrictive type until you tell it that the protocol will only be used by a `class` reference type.

Add conformance to `AnyObject` to your protocol to get reference type behavior:

```
protocol SampleProtocol: AnyObject {
    var message: String? { get set }
}
```

See [The Swift 5.1 Programming Guide - Class-Only Protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID281) for more details.

The guide notes:

> Use a class-only protocol when the behavior defined by that protocol’s
>   requirements assumes or requires that a conforming type has reference
>   semantics rather than value semantics.

---

**Historical note: Using `class` keyword**:

Prior to Swift 4.0, this was written using the `class` keyword:

```
protocol SampleProtocol: class {
    var message: String? { get set }
}
```

This still works for the time being, but it is currently just a type alias for `AnyObject` and will likely be removed in a later version of Swift.

Comment: this change has came on Swift 4: [https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md] This proposal merges the concepts of class and AnyObject, which now have the same meaning: they represent an existential for classes.

Comment: Thanks @TheCodeTalker.  I've been around Swift since Beta and occasionally one of these changes slips right by me.  Your link is broken BTW.

Comment: mistake correct link this  https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md

Comment: @vacawama thanks for putting more light on this. I'm aware that if I restrict my protocol to only class type then it gets a reference type. I was just curious about if it is intended to behave in this way.

Comment: The answer is yes, it is intended to behave that way.  As the guide says, if you want it to act like a reference, then tell Swift that `SampleProtocol` will only be adopted by classes.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t create a copy of the object. It is the same object in both calls – if you put `print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(sampleValue as AnyObject).toOpaque())` in didSet you will see that the address is the same. Compiler doesn’t know it’s dealing with a value type or a reference type. If you put a class keyword in protocol declaration like so:

```
protocol SampleProtocol: class { ... }
```

the didSet will be called once, because compiler knows it's a reference type and will not reassign reference.
I guess different setters generated depends on type of property